# How to resize an image in http response while my input image received to me in a plain data format?

Tags: django, image-resizing

I'm new in Django and recently I wrote a project about image representation.

in my view's function, I have a function in order to show images. but I first download the image from a service which is an encryption/decryption service.
it means that the downloaded image is in plain data byte format.

Now I want to write a new function to show that image in a smaller size instead of real size for faster loading. also, I want to show an image in another function as a cropped image.

How I can resize and crop images in the fastest way to save time waiting?

Comment: Please tell us what you tried so far? You current implementation and where you wanna achieve what. PIL/Pillow might be your friend though -> https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install python-resize-image
```

For example

```
from PIL import Image

from resizeimage import resizeimage


with open('test-image.jpeg', 'r+b') as f:
    with Image.open(f) as image:
        cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [200, 100])
        cover.save('test-image-cover.jpeg', image.format)
```

From https://pypi.org/project/python-resize-image/

Comment: Thank you for your response, but as I described above, I receive my image as a plain data and finally, I want to show image in Http response not to save it,

it is a part of my code:

DecryptResponseBytesPlainData = download_object(bject_name)

# some code to resize image


return HttpResponse(DecryptResponseBytesPlainData, content_type="image/png")